# Trying to monitor a product from a webpage, doesnt work as intented

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Very new to `requests`/`bs4`. I made a request to a webpage (a shop) and parsed it into a soup via bs4. If the soup contains the text "Sold Out" it should print me out "Sold Out", else "In Stock", but even though the body doesn't contain the word "Sold Out", it still prints "Sold Out"

I think there is a problem in formatting and I tried to change it to `soup.body.findAll(text="Sold Out")`

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("https://www.starcowparis.com/shoes/2030-adidas-alphaedge-4d-m.html")
src = (r.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
soup.find_all("div")



while True:
    soup.body.findAll(text="Sold Out")
    []
    print("Sold Out")
else:
    print("INSTOCK")
```

It always prints out "SOLD OUT" even though there is no "Sold Out" in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have a `while` loop where you want an `if` block:

```
if soup.body.findAll(text="Sold Out"):
    print("Sold Out")

else:
    print("INSTOCK")
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much for the answer of my first stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1):

The statement under `while True` will always be executed, because `True` will always be true no matter what.

What you want to do is using an `if` clause instead and check if the body contains any matches of the pattern `"Sold Out"`:

```py
if len(soup.body.findAll(text="Sold Out")) > 0:
    print("Sold Out")
else:
    print("INSTOCK")
```